# Not able to access Geth node from External Server

Tags: go-ethereum

I have hosted a geth node in a AWS machine using the below command

```
nohup  geth --networkid 12345 --verbosity 3 --ipcdisable --rpc --port 30301 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*" &
```

The node is working fine in the AWS machine. But i am unable to access the node externally from my localhost or any other computer outside the network. Even if when  i access the node from the external computer browser it does not give error instead gives a blank page. Not sure what's going wrong. In my local machine when i run the geth node and access it through browser it gives json output as

```
"{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}"
```

I tried the below command  to check weather the node is running or not on AWS

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":67}' http://xx.xxx.xxx.x:8545
```

This curl commands returns proper result.

I also tried with different configuration such as -rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*"  but it did not work.

Any suggestion why the node is not accessible outside the network. AM i missing any step. I want my geth node to be hosted on one AWS machine  and my application will access the node remotely.

Appreciate any suggestion. Thank you

Comment: check your firewall

Comment: If the curl command works from your computer then you are accessing the node. Do work other commands like `eth_blockNumber`? Perhaps you have to enable `--rpcapi=eth,web3,net`. How do you connect to the node from your app? Can you identify which commands are not working?